# How to filter a JSON array containing any of multiple elements

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

This is the sample table:

```
create table leadtime.test (
    id serial primary key,
    name jsonb
)
```

Data test:

```
insert into leadtime.test (name)
values ('["abc", "def", "ghi"]');
```

I want to check if name contains any value in this array '["abc", "132", "456"]'

I have to do this code:

```
select * from leadtime.test
where (name ? 'abc') or (name ? '132') or (name ? '456');
```

I was told that multiple `OR`'ed filters or not optimal for performance.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your array of search terms as actual Postgres array and use the [**`|?`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  name ?| '{abc, def, ghi}';
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

> `jsonb ?| text[] → boolean`
>
> Do any of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or
> array elements?

Can be supported with a plain [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) on `(name)`, too.